# Widget rebuilds when keyboard popup

Tags: flutter, keyboard, widget, icons

According to this [Why does my widget rebuild when I use keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244573/why-does-my-widget-rebuild-when-i-use-keyboard) problem is Mediaquery but i replaced it with methodchannel to get statusbar height for padding on top

but it still rebuilds when keyboard popups

[image: keyboard popup rebuild]

```
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: MediaQueryData.fromView(View.of(context)).padding.top, //replaced back to mediaquery to avoid boilerplate
        // top: statusBarHeight,
        left: 10,
        right: 10,
      ),
      child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: 1.0,
        minChildSize: 0.99,
        maxChildSize: 1.0,
        expand: true,
        snap: true,
        builder: (context, scrollController) {
          return Column(
            // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
            children: [
              // Serarch Bar in Drawer
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: widget._textEditingController,
                  onSubmitted: (value) {
                    widget.appops.openApps(widget.appops.searchAppList[0]);
                    // clearText();
                    // setState(() {
                    //   appops.searchApp('');
                    // });
                  },
                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.appops.searchApp(context, value);
                    });
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(color: widget.themeTextColor),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
                    focusColor: widget.themeTextColor,
                    hintText: "Search",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: widget.themeTextColor),
                    filled: true,
                    // fillColor: sysBrightness ? Colors.grey[900] : Colors.grey[200],
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: widget._textEditingController.text != ''
                        ? IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                            onPressed: () {
                              widget.clearText();
                              setState(() {
                                widget.appops.searchApp(context, '');
                              });
                            },
                          )
                        : const Text(''),
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              widget.setIcon
                  ? Flexible(
                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                              // width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width - 60,
                              width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width - 20,
                              // width: constraints.maxWidth - 20,
                              // child: Scrollbar(
                              child: Scrollbar(
                                controller: scrollController,
                                interactive: true,
                                // thumbVisibility: true,
                                radius: const Radius.circular(10),
                                // trackVisibility: true,
                                thickness: 10,

                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  child: GridView.builder(
                                      cacheExtent: 9999,
                                      controller: scrollController,
                                      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                        crossAxisCount: 4,
                                        childAspectRatio: 0.9,
                                        mainAxisSpacing: 30,
                                        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                        // mainAxisExtent: 110,
                                      ),
                                      itemCount: widget.appops.searchAppList.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                        final appsls = widget.appops.searchAppList[index];

                                        // String currentLetter = getFirstLetter(appls.appName);

                                        // bool shouldDisplaySeparator =
                                        //     index == 0 || currentLetter != getFirstLetter(appops.searchAppList[index - 1].appName);

                                        if (widget.appops.searchAppList.isNotEmpty) {
                                          return AppGridItem(
                                            appls: appsls,
                                            themeTextColor: widget.themeTextColor,
                                            addToDock: widget.addToDock,
                                            loadApps: widget.loadApps,
                                            appops: widget.appops,
                                            sysBrightness: widget.sysBrightness,
                                            dockIconList: widget.dockIconList,
                                          );
                                        } else {
                                          return const Expanded(
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text('Loading...'),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }
                                      }),
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  : Flexible(
                      child: Row(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                            // width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width - 60,
                            width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width - 20,
                            child: Scrollbar(
                              controller: scrollController,
                              interactive: true,
                              // thumbVisibility: true,
                              radius: const Radius.circular(10),
                              // trackVisibility: true,
                              thickness: 10,
                              child: ListView.separated(
                                cacheExtent: 9999,
                                controller: scrollController,
                                itemCount: widget.appops.searchAppList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  final appls = widget.appops.searchAppList[index];
                                  String currentLetter = widget.getFirstLetter(appls.appName);

                                  // Check if the separator should be displayed
                                  bool shouldDisplaySeparator =
                                      index == 0 || currentLetter != widget.getFirstLetter(widget.appops.searchAppList[index - 1].appName);
                                  return widget.appops.searchAppList.isNotEmpty
                                      ? AppListItem(
                                          appls: appls,
                                          themeTextColor: widget.themeTextColor,
                                          addToDock: widget.addToDock,
                                          loadApps: widget.loadApps,
                                          appops: widget.appops,
                                          sysBrightness: widget.sysBrightness,
                                          dockIconList: widget.dockIconList,
                                          shouldDisplaySeparator: shouldDisplaySeparator,
                                          currentLetter: currentLetter)
                                      : const Center(
                                          child: Text('Loading...'),
                                        );
                                },
                                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return const SizedBox.shrink(); // Return an empty separator when the letter doesn't change
                                  // }
                                  // }
                                },
                              ),
                            )),
                      ],
                    )),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Using  device_apps: ^2.2.0 to display application and its icons

How do i prevent it from rebuilding icon images / widget?

Comment: Stop using MediaQuery.  Learn to use the other layout widgets, like FractionallySizedBox.  You should almost never do math directly on pixels.

Comment: How do i get statusbar height by using FractionallySizedBox

Answer (score 0):

If your return is Scaffold and use AppBar. Your widget will automatically have padding top, distance with statusbar. This happens because AppBar widget.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(),
   body: Text(),
 );
}
```

But if your return is another widget like DraggableScrollableSheet, you must use [SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) widget. That widget will give padding top based on flutter calculation.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: DraggableScrollableSheet (),
 );
}
```

Of course after let the flutter give distance between top screen with statusbar, you can add padding widget to give more distance.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
   child: DraggableScrollableSheet ();
  ),
 );
}
```